# Marginal distributions: Sheldon Ross book example

Tags: self-study, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

i was stuck on the 27th theoretical exercise of chapter 6 of Sheldon Ross's book: A first course in probability.

Suppose we have two continuous random variables:

$X \sim Uniform(0,1)$ and $Y \sim Exponential (1)$.

I'm interested in $Z = X + Y$ or $W = \frac{X}{Y}$

How can i find the distribution of Z or W? I saw an answer in a Solution Manual, and there assume that X and Y are  two independent random variables. Do i need to assume that necessarily? Otherwise i can never know the joint distribution right?

Comment: You should tag this as self-study, please. And read its tag wiki.

Comment: Yes, I think you're meant to assume that the two random variables are independent. It's possible to design situations in which the marginal distributions look like things like Uniform(0,1) but are jointly dependent (e.g. copulas); but that's probably not intended here as IMO it would be quite advanced.

Comment: To find the joint distributions of $Z$ and $W$ respectively it would be required to remove the dependence from $X$ and $Y$ (by using integration) first.

Comment: I think you will have to use convolution...